# Color a specific div when column X has a value of ACCEPTED

Tags: php, html, css, database

I'm kinda stuck somehow, somewhere.. I put 3 comments in my code below because I know its where I need to work on. What I want to do is to color a specific ID/CLASS div when my column statut == 'Accepted'', another specific color if...well, you can guess by my code. The thing is, I don't know how and in what language I should do it. css? html?

```
public function Show($name) {
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$name'");
        $st->execute();
            $results = $st->fetchobject();
                if($results->statut == 'ACCEPTED'){
                      // color my div in green.
                } else if ($results->statut == 'REFUSER'){
                      // color my div in red.
                } else {
                      // color my div in yellow.
                }
        while($r = $st->fetch()){
                    echo '<div class="SupInfo">';
            echo '<hr>';
            echo 'Votre adresse : '.$r['Adresse'].'<br>';
            echo 'Votre met : '.$r['Met'].'<br>';
            echo 'Votre age : '.$r['Age'].'<br>';
            echo 'Statut : '.$r['Statut'].'<br>';
            echo '<hr>';
                    echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: pass class into $var like '$class= 'Supinfo'. ' accepted'; and echo it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to a variable the class name of the div in your condition

```
public function Show($name) {
    $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$name'");
    $st->execute();
    $results = $st->fetchobject();
    if($results->statut == 'ACCEPTED'){
        $color = 'green';
    } else if ($results->statut == 'REFUSER'){
        $color = 'red';
    } else {
        $color = 'yellow';
    }
    while($r = $st->fetch()) {          
        echo '<div class="'.$color.'">';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo 'Votre adresse : '.$r['Adresse'].'<br>';
        echo 'Votre met : '.$r['Met'].'<br>';
        echo 'Votre age : '.$r['Age'].'<br>';
        echo 'Statut : '.$r['Statut'].'<br>';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

But i think this won't give you the expected output because all divs will be colored with the status of the first record selected, maybe you need something different

```
public function Show($name) {
    $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$name'");
    $st->execute();
    $results = $st->fetchobject();
    while($r = $st->fetch()) {     
        if($r['statut'] == 'ACCEPTED') {
            echo '<div class="green">';
        } else if($r['statut'] == 'REFUSER') {
            echo '<div class="red">';
        } else { 
            echo '<div class="yellow">';
        }
        echo '<hr>';
        echo 'Votre adresse : '.$r['Adresse'].'<br>';
        echo 'Votre met : '.$r['Met'].'<br>';
        echo 'Votre age : '.$r['Age'].'<br>';
        echo 'Statut : '.$r['Statut'].'<br>';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Now you just need to add to your stylesheet file something like

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Every div is in yellow. +, above each div there is an error : Notice: Undefined index: statut in [...]\connection.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: statut in [...]\connection.php on line 41

Answer (score 0):

php

```
public function Show($name) {
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$name'");
        $st->execute();
            $results = $st->fetchobject();
                if($results->statut == 'ACCEPTED'){
                      $class = 'green'; // color my div in green.
                } else if ($results->statut == 'REFUSER'){
                      $class = 'red';  // color my div in red.
                } else {
                      $class = 'yellow';  // color my div in yellow.
                }
        while($r = $st->fetch()){
                    echo "<div class=\"$class\">";
            echo '<hr>';
            echo 'Votre adresse : '.$r['Adresse'].'<br>';
            echo 'Votre met : '.$r['Met'].'<br>';
            echo 'Votre age : '.$r['Age'].'<br>';
            echo 'Statut : '.$r['Statut'].'<br>';
            echo '<hr>';
                    echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

css

```
 .green{background:green}
 .yellow{background:yellow}
 .red{background:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the css class when condition meets i.e

```
public function Show($name) {
    $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$name'");
    $st->execute();
        $results = $st->fetchobject();
            if($results->statut == 'ACCEPTED'){
                  echo "<div class='green'></div>";
            } else if ($results->statut == 'REFUSER'){
                  echo "<div class='red'></div>";
            } else {
                  echo "<div class='yellow'></div>";
            }
    while($r = $st->fetch()){
                echo '<div class="SupInfo">';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo 'Votre adresse : '.$r['Adresse'].'<br>';
        echo 'Votre met : '.$r['Met'].'<br>';
        echo 'Votre age : '.$r['Age'].'<br>';
        echo 'Statut : '.$r['Statut'].'<br>';
        echo '<hr>';
                echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

And in your CSS have following classes:

```
 .green
{background:green}
 .yellow
{background:yellow}
 .red
{background:red}
```